# Have issue with JSON

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an issue with json parsing
-I established a connection to a remote server to receive a json object, which looks like this

```
2011-08-31 13:23:27.280 WallpaperBackground[731:40b] jsonString:{"photoset":{"id":"72157627554107638", "primary":"6095921496", "owner":"66801517@N05",  "ownername":"Gariya1", "photo":[{"id":"6096223569", "secret":"47081ffe65", "server":"6202", "farm":7, "title":"snakc", "isprimary":"0"}, {"id":"6095921496", "secret":"ea3b2b5076", "server":"6064", "farm":7, "title":"images", "isprimary":"1"},
```

-In the didReceiveData method, I assigned the json string

code:

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then I built my dictionary

code:

```
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];
```

when i am runing this, In console i am getting these error

```
 2011-08-31 13:23:27.284 WallpaperBackground[731:40b] -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
"Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=5 \"Unescaped control character '0x0'\" UserInfo=0x4e1d670 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unescaped control character '0x0'}",
"Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object value expected for key: server\" UserInfo=0x4e1d7c0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x4e1d6d0 \"Unescaped control character '0x0'\", NSLocalizedDescription=Object value expected for key: server}",
"Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Expected value while parsing array\" UserInfo=0x4e1d810 {NSUnderlyingError=0x4e1d7a0 \"Object value expected for key: server\", NSLocalizedDescription=Expected value while parsing array}",
"Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object value expected for key: photo\" UserInfo=0x4e1d8d0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x4e1d890 \"Expected value while parsing array\", NSLocalizedDescription=Object value expected for key: photo}",
"Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object value expected for key: photoset\" UserInfo=0x4e1d980 {NSUnderlyingError=0x4e1d8b0 \"Object value expected for key: photo\", NSLocalizedDescription=Object value expected for key: photoset}"
```

If any one knw let me help out pl... thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiate a `NSMutableData`, preferably public in your interface definition found in your `.h` file.
Every time `connection:didReceiveData:` is called, use the `NSMutableData's "appendData:data"` method to add the newly received data to the variable.

When your `connection:didFinishLoading:` method is called, you will have a completely filled `NSMutableData` object waiting to be parsed.
Then call the `SBJSONParser's` method to parse it like you did.

EDIT

You declare a `NSMutableData` object in your .h file.

Whenever your connection object calls its delegate method `DidReceiveData` you will append the data as follows:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [publicDataObject appendData:data];
}
```

When the data is completely downloaded you will be left an object with your complete data in it.
So then in your finishedLoading method:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:publicDataObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    id results = [jsonString JSONValue];
}
```

If you know for sure what the resulting datatype will be you can change the datatype of the results variable from id to i.e. NSDictionary, or NSArray.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can u give me example related to that

Comment: Can you please mark this question answered, if this was the answer that solved your problem. Thanks in advance! And no problem, glad I could be of service.

Answer (score 0):

The `connection:didReceiveData:` method will be called multiple times as parts of the data are loaded. You cannot assume that the data is complete until `connection:didFinishLoading:` is called. Until then, you have to concatenate the chunks of data in a buffer (like `NSMutableData`).